# Highcharts Dynamic Gradient based on Y-Axis values

Tags: highcharts

In the following sample chart - https://jsfiddle.net/fujigoko/rkp2mdf7/1/ - I have a very hardcoded gradient defined as follows:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    plotBackgroundColor: {
      linearGradient: [0, 300, 0, 0],
      stops: [
        [0, 'yellow'],
        [1, 'green']
      ]
    }
  },
```

What I actually need is a gradient with 4 stops depending on the Y-Axis values:

- yellow at the minimum value of the Y axis, whatever it may be based on the data
- yellow at value 150
- green at value 250
- green at the maximum value of the Y axis, whatever it may be based on the data

I have been trying unsuccessfully to convert values into pixels and using the yAxis.Max to do this. Is this something that can be done with Highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the stops, I recommend using the x1, x2, y1, y2 attributes of the linearGradient. You can dynamically get the yAxis positions at the chart's load event. Also, `yAxis.toPixels()` will be useful in this use case.

**Example code:**

```
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        let chart = this,
          yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
          gradient = {
            linearGradient: {
              x1: 0,
              y1: 1,
              x2: 0,
              y2: 0
            },
            stops: [
              [0, 'yellow'],
              [(chart.plotHeight - yAxis.toPixels(150, true)) / chart.plotHeight, 'yellow'],
              [(chart.plotHeight - yAxis.toPixels(250, true)) / chart.plotHeight, 'green'],
              [1, 'green']
            ]
          };

        chart.update({
          chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: gradient
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4v3xreq6/

**API References:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

Comment: Had no idea I could use the load event - that makes a lot of sense :) thank you so much! I need to study more about events in Highcharts!

Comment: You're welcome ;) I recommend checking out this article: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/introduction-to-highcharts-events/. Also, here's a demo that illustrates the differences between Load, Redraw, and Render: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-render/. Regards!